# How to strip vowels/nekudot/diacritics from hebrew utf-8 in ruby?

Tags: ruby, utf-8, hebrew

Hebrew prints vowels as nekudot/points around the letters. 
with vowels: " יִתְגַּבֵּר כַּאֲרִי לַעֲמֹד בַּבֹּקֶר לַעֲבוֹדַת בּוֹרְאוֹ שֶׁיְּהֵא הוּא מְעוֹרֵר הַשַּׁחַר" 
without vowels: "יתגב כארי לעמוד בבקר לעבודת בוראו שיהא הוא מעורר השחר"

I need a way to strip these vowels from a string. As in convert the string, with vowels, to the string, without vowels. Any suggestions?

-p.s.

I have tried "hebrew.gsub(/[^א-ת]/, '')"
but this has two problems: a: this will remove all punctuation, english, etc. I only want to remove the vowels. b: some letters get removed as well. (my understanding is limited, but it seems some letters/vowel combinations become "multibyte" in utf-8 and will not match "א-ת".

I found this:https://gist.github.com/yakovsh/345a71d841871cc3d375 online, but the ruby suggestion only works with rails, (assuming it works at all).
However, perhaps that page can be helpful in finding a solution.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The vowels are all between U+0591 and U+05C7, so you can just do

```
hebrew.gsub(/[\u0591-\u05c7]/,"")
```

e.g.

```
" יִתְגַּבֵּר כַּאֲרִי לַעֲמֹד בַּבֹּקֶר לַעֲבוֹדַת בּוֹרְאוֹ שֶׁיְּהֵא הוּא מְעוֹרֵר הַשַּׁחַר".gsub(/[\u0591-\u05c7]/,"")
# => " יתגבר כארי לעמד בבקר לעבודת בוראו שיהא הוא מעורר השחר"
```

However, that only works if the vowels are all separate characters in the string - or to say the same thing in Unicode-speak, if the text is in Normalization Form D. You can ensure that is the case by calling [`String#unicode_normalize`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/unicode_normalize/rdoc/String.html#method-i-unicode_normalize) on it first:

```
hebrew.unicode_normalize(:nfd).gsub(/[\u0591-\u05c7]/,"")
```

This step is necessary because Unicode includes several individual characters that combine a letter with *nekuddot* in a single code point, for round-trip compatibility with older character sets that did not support combining diacritics. Those characters mean you can't tell just by looking whether the string "בּ" consists of the two-code-point sequence `U+05D1 HEBREW LETTER BET` followed by `U+05BC HEBREW POINT DAGESH OR MAPIQ`, or just the single character `U+FB31 HEBREW LETTER BET WITH DAGESH`. Putting the string into Normalization Form D replaces the latter with the former, and also splits up any other "precomposed" characters into their component parts.

Comment: i am still getting back: יִתגּבּר כּארי לעמד בּבּקר לעבוֹדת בּוֹראוֹ שׁיּהא הוּא מעוֹרר השּׁחר. so it works a little, but notice "גּבּ" and "שּׁ"

Comment: it works completely for me. Maybe your text has some of the precomposed characters from the Presentation Forms block? In which case, you need to normalize it first. Try `h.unicode_normalize(:nfd).gsub(/[\u0591-\u05c7]/,"")`

Comment: Finally! That did it! Thank you.